# Jquery UI Autocomplete Doesn't Display List in IE

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I'm trying to build an autocomplete input following the example from http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote. So far, the codes work in Opera, Firefox and Chrome, but not in IE8 and IE9. Below are my codes and the response from the server for TestData.

Have been testing these for the past few days with no success. Would appreciate it any gurus here can help.

Thanks.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $( "#test" ).autocomplete({
                    source: "TestData",
                    minLength: 2
                });
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="ui-widget">
            <input id="test" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Response headers from server

```
Key             Value
Response        HTTP/1.0 200 
Server          Development/1.0
Date            Mon, 26 Nov 2012 02:49:31 GMT
Cache-Control   no-cache
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf8
Content-Length  43
```

Response body

```
[{"id":"1","value":"a1","label":"a1 test"}]
```

Comment: no error message on IE's status bar

Answer (score 0):

For finer grained control of what is actually returned by web service, I would recommend implementing this way:

```
$( "#city" ).autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.ajax({
                    .............
                    success: function( data ) {
                        var transformedData = transformData(data);
                        // feeding back to jquery autocomplete 
                        response( transformedData );
                    }
                });
            });
```

You should be able to see what you are getting from web service in debugger if you'll set the breakpoint in the success function.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to JQuery and have tried your code above but have got this error: 'transformData' is undefined. Also, I've placed the response from the server above. This response I got from 'F12 developer tools'

Comment: transformData is the place-holder for your function, in case you need data transformation. if the data is already in the jquery-autocomplete format, just pass the data to the response(data);